# eventpreventdefault() not working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on php files. I created ajax jquery function to handle delete and display uploaded file. When i want to delete files event.preventdefault() function not working in firefox but it working fine in chrome browser. How can i solve this.

```
/* Read Upload Files */
function readuploadfiles(jrsid){
    var jourid = jrsid;
   //console.log("Journal Id: "+jourid);
    //var evt = e || window.event; 
  //evt.preventDefault();
    $.get("readuploadfiles.php", {jid: jourid}, function (data) {
      //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      console.log(data);
       $('#uploadfiles').html(data); 

    }); 
    return false;   
}
 /* Delete upload file */
function deleteuploadfiles(id){
  var conf = confirm("Are you sure, do you really want to delete file?");
    if (conf == true) {    
    event.preventDefault();
        $.post("deleteuploadfile.php", {id: id}, function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              readuploadfiles(data);               
            }
        );
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is `event` comming from?

Comment: I didn't understand.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the event.

```
   function deleteuploadfiles(id, **event**){
```

and also:

```
   $( "your button" ).click(function( **event** ) {
   deleteuploadfiles(id, event)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `preventDefault` method is only accessible if you have access to the event object that is passed in to your method when an event is triggered. Meaning, in order for `event.preventDefault()` to work, you'll first need to accept the `event` object in your method. You'll need something like this:

```
function deleteuploadfiles(event, id){
    // Now you can use the event object
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Hope that helps.